# Telegram: Store chat id or Channel with bot inside?

Tags: python, telegram, telegram-bot

I'm starting to learn telegram bot. My plan was to have a bot that daily sends you at a specific time a message, but also I wanted the option to manually poll the bot for getting that daily message, or a random one. Right now I have a bot running on pythonanywhere that can respond to the 2 commands, but what about sending the user the daily message at some time? 
What's the way to go, create a channel and then schedule a task on my webhook to daily send the message to the channel, or store all chat-id in my service and talk to them everytime? The first one seems obviously better but I was wondering if there's some trick to make everything works in the bot.

Answer (score 0):

For now I managed to create a channel, make the bot an admin and scheduled a task on the webhook to daily send a message as admin to the channel